# ImportError: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory & Permission denied as well

Tags: python

I am using jupyter notebook in my linux environment using mozilla firefox. I am getting this error will running the file.

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d75dbb064b62> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('apt update && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6')
----> 2 import tkinter as tk
      3 from tkinter import filedialog
      4 from tkinter import *
      5 from PIL import ImageTk, Image

/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py in <module>
     34 import sys
     35 
---> 36 import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
     37 TclError = _tkinter.TclError
     38 from tkinter.constants import *

ImportError: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: try  `yum -y install tkinter`

Answer (score 0):

try `conda install -c conda-forge xorg-libx11`